# Link back to the visited URL before

Tags: python, django, url

I have a city card that I display with this link:

```
/<country_name>/<city_name>
```

I can access to this card from two different links:

```
/<country_name>/
/<country_name>/pick-cities
```

When the card is opened I want to return back to the URL visited before (one of the two below).
I have used a target which I affect a referring:

```
target = request.META['HTTP_REFERER']
```

But the problem is when I make some actions on the card then `request.META['HTTP_REFERER']` become the card's URL! (like `history.back()` in JavaScript)
Is there an other way to link back to the visited URL before?

Comment: Maybe make those actions in AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

You could save the `request.META['HTTP_REFERER']` in sessions and use it when needed.

Store it only when you come to card url which is different from current url, so you will not save it when you edit it.

Something like

```
def city_card(request):
    # do your stuff
    if not request.session.get('REFERRER') and request.session['REFERRER'] != request.path
        request.session['REFERRER'] = request.path

    # use request.session['REFERRER'] when you want to redirect there
```

NOTE: You may have to use something else than `request.path` to actual url verification.

Comment: it return KeyError: 'REFERER' !!